# Solution to the equation $x^3-3=2\sqrt{x+2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, radicals

> Solve the equation $x^3-3=2\sqrt{x+2}$.

I have tried to let $t=\sqrt{x+2}$ then we have 
$$\begin{cases}
 x^3-3&=2t \tag 1\\ 
 t^2 &=x+2 
\end{cases}$$
But I've stuck here...

Any help or advice on solving is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you expect clean answers? This is equivalent to asking for roots of a sixth degree polynomial, which Wolfram Alpha can't find a closed form for

Comment: Square both sides

Comment: And humans cant find it i suppose

Answer (score 4):

$$x^3-3=2\sqrt{x+2}$$
$$x^6-6x^3+9=4x+8$$
$$x^6-6x^3-4x+1=0$$
At this point we get a sixth degree polynomial, and you can estimate the roots accordingly. [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3-3%3D2%5Csqrt%7Bx%2B2%7D) gives the positive solution as $x \approx 1.90874157798\dots$, but cannot find a closed form for the points (this can happen while solving any polynomial of degree $5$ of higher, by a proof by Galois)

Comment: RHS should be 4x+8.

Comment: @AshishGupta Good catch, thank you. I have corrected the post accordingly.

Comment: Some polynomials of degree 5 or higher can be solved exactly; $x^8=1$, for instance. The *general* polynomial of degree 5 (or larger) isn't, though.

Comment: @kimtahe6 If you are interested in approaching the root of this equation, you can always use methods of numerical analysis, for example the Newton - Raphson method (though it's not an algebra precalculus exercise for sure).

Comment: @CarlHeckman True. I don't mean to imply that you can't solve some of degree higher 5 or higher in my post above... I just say that not being able to solve such an equation *can* occur from time to time, which is definitely true. Your example is a key example of why this does not hold in general though :)

Comment: Thanks everyone. But I have a question that a person WHO have REDUCED my vote, why?  I posted my problem here, it doesn't violate the rules of the site. I think that someone had not cultural behavior as REDUCED my vote.

Comment: @kimtahe6 the problem is less that people are uncultured and more that you don't give context for the problem, which is within site guidelines. Some people down vote a lot more than others, and thats my best guess what would have made someone do so.

Comment: @ Brevan Ellefsen: Then you should have said "a", not "any".

Comment: @CarlHeckman Ah yes, I see the difference now... I suppose I use them interchangeably too often and I make this mistake from time to time in formal writing. Well noted, I see where you were coming from.